# Sent some testnet Bitcoin to Bitcoin Core wallet but balance is still zero

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, testnet, bitcoin-cli, balance

I got the testnet Bitcoin address with this command:

`bitcoin-cli -testnet getnewaddress`

And here is the Bitcoin address:
`2NDtNjDbEiNiKDuAnwyKBmRPQ49NNpesdhE`

As you can see in [blockchain](https://insight.bitcore.io/#/BTC/testnet/tx/25619e18a30723475fb32f5ecae015d272cf916d234032704176568517561437) there was a confirmed transaction.

I checked my balance with this command:

```
bitcoin-cli -testnet getbalance
```

but the balance is `0.00000000`

What is wrong here and how to fix this problem?

Comment: Is your node synced?

Comment: @RaghavSood I just checked that with `bitcoin-cli -testnet getblockchaininfo` and `verificationprogress` field shows it is `0.232278556934958`.

Comment: So no, it is not synced.  Wait until it is, and then your balance should reflect this transaction.